# How to set tax in price magento

Tags: content-management-system, magento, webshop

**I have 2 shops with same settings imo.**

**My question is how do I get my prices including tax in my second shop?
Both have settings like this**

[image]

**My first shop includes tax (see picture)**

[image]

**My second shop does not show this**

[image]

Any idea how i can get this done?

The problem is that all my prices are being taxed on the homepage now.
So if i say the amount must be €100 it makes it €119 now and i don't want that.

Any help is realy appreaciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your two stores must be separate websites. That is, in System > Manage Stores they must have different values in the "Website Name" column. The next step is impossible without this.

Now go back to System > Configuration > Tax page, in the top left corner change the "Configuration Scope" drop-down to the website for the second shop, then change the "Catalog Prices" to "Excluding Tax".

Comment: Thanks, clockwork. It wasn't the answer where I was looking for but it helped me out! I had two stores already and I saved your settings, turned it back to the old settings as on the pictures and now it works! Probebly some bug in Magento that he needed some refreshment of settings? Anyway thanks for helping out!